# Node module was compiled against node module v 72. v 64 is requred

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I'm adding music streaming to my Discord bot and the only issue i'm currently having is this:

```
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at bindings (/home/pi/Eterna/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Eterna/node_modules/node-opus/lib/OpusEncoder.js:4:34)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
(node:27501) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27501) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Ive tried npm rebuild and npm rebuild opusscript --update-binary
and had no luck. I've looked at similar situations but (not sure if this helps) all of their versions were switched like where mine is

"was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64."

theirs would be

"was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69."

their compiled against version was lower than the required
Just thought i'd point that out.

I just tried downgrading node to 10.18.0 (last one using module v 64) Same issue. still says i have 72

Comment: what's the output of `npm rebuild`? did you also try `npm ci`?

Comment: there's no output it just goes back to terminal. However i just tried npm ci and it works perfectly. Thanks